# I resarch about HDFS failures. For this I need to HDFS logs . Where can I download the logs?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-partitioning, webhdfs

I  resarch about HDFS failures. For this I need to HDFS logs . Where can I download the logs ?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the logs directory inside HADOOP_HOME directory. All datanode, nodemanager, namenode etc. logs are available there.